# Target main .as file in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to target a variable in the main *.as* file (The one that acts as the *stage*) from another *.as* file.

```
public var stageRef:MovieClip = root as MovieClip;
```

or

```
MovieClip(root)variable = 10;
```

don't seem to want to work for me. Neither of them produce any compile errors but when I try to use them they give me a 1009 error, *cannot access a property or a null object reference*. Any ideas of how i would go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question shows that you have very little knowledge of AS3 or any other language at that matter. You should start with some book for beginners and do some tutorials. Or at least try google'ing for an answer first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im your Main.as class make the variable public. Here's an example:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public var YOUR_VAR_HERE:VARIABLE_TYPE = DEFAULT_VALUE;
        public function Main()
        {

        }

    }
}
```

DEFAULT_VALUE is optional. VARIABLE_TYPE is recommended, if not specified the type will be Object by default.

There are many ways to pass a variable to another class. If the class is created inside the Main class, just pass the variable to that class like this:

```
var myOtherClass:OtherClass = new OtherClass(YOUR_VAR_HERE);
```

or

```
var myOtherClass:OtherClass = new OtherClass();
myOtherClass.varReference = YOUR_VAR_HERE;
```

In first case make sure the constructor is expecting a variable. In the second, make sure the OtherClass has a public variable varReference that you can access and modify.

Another way loved by newbie programmers are static (singleton) variables: in the Main class specify your variable as such:

```
public static var YOUR_VAR_HERE:VARIABLE_TYPE = DEFAULT_VALUE;
```

Then you can access YOUR_VAR_HERE simply by referring to the class Main. Like this:

```
trace(Main.YOUR_VAR_HERE);
```

**NOTE:** it's considered to use all uppercase letters for constants, not variables, in this case I used all caps for readability.